# A way to query custom taxonomies by name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query

I am trying to build an AJAX form that auto populates based on what the user types in. So I need to be able to query my custom post taxonomy.

So basically I have a list of cities as a custom taxonomy. If the user starts typing "newcastle" i need to be able to query the custom post type taxonomy.

Now I can get all the taxonomy's out using:

```
get_terms( 'hotellocation', 'hide_empty=0' );
```

But I want to be able to query the terms and only display relevant terms on the output. Is there a way of doing this without SQL (trying to keep everything inside wordpress using their terms)

The SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'taxterms' WHERE 'name' LIKE %newcastle%
```

It would then output something like:

- Newcastle Upon Tyne
- Newcastle under Lyme

Comment: Why not use city names as real meta data per post? You could then query by unique meta data per post.. here is a tutorial- https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/mastering-wordpress-meta-data-querying-posts-and-users-by-meta-data--wp-34606

Answer (score 0):

You can add a search field to get_terms arguments, which will have wildcards added by WordPress automatically:

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'search' => $searched_term,
);
get_terms('hotellocation', $args);
```

This is documented about mid-way down the page [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/). There are also other similar arguments you could use, such as `name__like`, if `search` doesn't work for whatever reason.